# Search String using Regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get every occurrence of a substring using regex, but it is not quite working

```
$txt='[[Created::11 January 2014]][[Assignee::David]][[Assignee::root]][[Title::Test]]';

$re1='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='(\\[\\[Assignee::.*?\\]\\])';     # Square Braces 1

preg_match_all ("/".$re2."/", $txt, $matches);

$sbraces1=$matches[1][0];
$sbraces2=$matches[2][0];
print "($sbraces1) ($sbraces2) \n";
```

> Output:  ([[Assignee::David]]) ()

The string can contain an arbitrary number of Assignees and I need to filter every one of them. An array containing the Assignees' names would be perfect, but as you can see preg_match_all(...) finds only the first match and I do not know why. 
what is wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Best Regards
David

Comment: that's not quite right, it doesn't *find* just one, you only *display* the first. $matches[1] contains *all* matches of the first subpattern (which is [[Assignee::<whatever>]])), and of that you only display [0]. That means that probably [1] also exists. Do a var_dump on $matches to see them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues:
1. You're not actually showing all assignees that are matched. Rather you only show the first (due to your $matches[1][0] and $matches[2][0] fields (which show the FIRST match of both subpatterns).
2. You might want to show only the name of the assignee and not the entire text.

Try it like this:

```
<?php
$txt='[[Created::11 January 2014]][[Assignee::David]][[Assignee::root]][[Title::Test]]';

preg_match_all ('#\\[\\[Assignee::(.+)\\]\\]#U', $txt, $matches); // The U modifier makes this UNgreedy

$matched_assignees = implode(', ', $matches[1]); // we now glue together all the assignees matched with a ", " between them to form a nice long string.
echo 'Matched assignees: ', $matched_assignees; // output them
```